# How to set up Plyr Ads with Daiylmotion Video

Tags: ads, plyr, dailymotion-api

I am looking for a sample working solution showing Plyr Ads on Dailymotion Video as preroll.
There is a good example with Plyr ads and Youtube Video here which works fine.
https://ferdiemmen.github.io/plyr-ads/

There is a code inside which should be changed to Dailymotion but needs probably a Dailymotion plugins.

Exact the same Code I would like to have with Dailymotion video instead of Youtube.

Please if someone can help then step by step for newby.

Thanks
Sami

Answer (score 0):

The Dailymotion player is still not implemented in the Plyr library.

Most of the job as been done: a pull request (updated 5 days ago) need to be fixed before merging: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/pull/2136